# Getting Error when capturing the Opt value

Tags: c

I am calling a function `menu_display1(&table,rows,&opt);` in my file and the definition of that function is given below.. 
Here table is a resultset contains id, name and cols=30

```
int  menu_display1( resultset *table,int cols,char *opt[])
{
        char *menu_list[table->rows + 1];
        int i;


        if(table->rows > 0 && strcmp(table->recordset[0][0], "") != 0)
        {

                for(i=0; i<(table->rows); i++)
                {
                        menu_list[i] = table->recordset[i][1];
                }
                lk_dispclr();
                *opt=scroll_menu1(menu_list,i);
        printf("The selected category name is %s",*opt);
                 // if(*opt==CANCEL)
                    //   return CANCEL;

        }
       return SUCCESS;//# define SUCCESS 1
}
```

i need to capture the value from opt and i need to print it..

```
printf("The option value is %s \n",opt);
```

But i am getting garbage values in `opt`..I dont know how to handle the opt value...

Comment: So basically you're asking someone to debug `printf("%s",scroll_menu1(menu_list,i));` but you didn't supply the source code of `scroll_menu1`.  How are we supposed to figure this out?  I suggest simplifying your program to the smallest possible program that exhibits the problem and then posting the entire thing.

Comment: @Davi..... this is the scrol_menu function code...

Comment: No, this is the code for `menu_display1`

Answer (score 0):

That's because `opt` is an array of strings.  To dereference it you need to use `*opt` or `opt[0]`.

Comment: @Nahtan Fellman       Yaeh i tried *opt also... but getting garbage values again.....